# QUERY Function Question Regarding WHERE clause

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a query where I am trying to match the range value with the value that is in the first column (A) of the current row:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://URL.com", Spreadsheet!A:Z), "SELECT COl4 WHERE Col1 = "' & CONCATENATE('A', ROW()) & '")`

So essentially, I am trying to select the value of col4 if col1 matches the value of "A235" or A + whatever the current row is.

However the Concatenate part doesn't seem to be working (Formula parse error) and if someone could point me in the right direction, it will be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: A typo in a formula? `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://URL.com", Spreadsheet!A:Z), "SELECT COl4 WHERE Col1 = '" & CONCATENATE("A", ROW()) & "'")`

Comment: Or just `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://URL.com", Spreadsheet!A:Z), "SELECT COl4 WHERE Col1 = 'A" & ROW() & "'")`

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! However the query still returns empty output even though:

`"SELECT Col4 WHERE Col1 = '"&A235&"'"`

Returns a result

Comment: Can you share the spreadsheet or a copy to see the data and the expected result?

Comment: @Cuppy Ah! You need a value from `A235` and not just a string `"A235"`. My bad. This should work `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://URL.com", Spreadsheet!A:Z), "SELECT COl4 WHERE Col1 = '& A:A & "'")`

Comment: @kishkin, Wow that worked great!

There's a missing " in the formula you gave but it was otherwise perfect, thanks a bunch!

Adding the missing ":
`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://URL.com", Spreadsheet!A:Z), "SELECT COl4 WHERE Col1 = '" & A:A & "'")`

Answer (score 1):

Repeating a working solution from my comment.

Try this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://URL.com", Spreadsheet!A:Z), "SELECT COl4 WHERE Col1 = '" & A:A & "'")
```